# Make text scroll on any key press HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if there was any way to mimic the text scrolling on holding a key, similar to what is seen on https://hackertyper.net/
I would preferably do this in HTML, CSS and JS.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post any code you've written to try to make this work? What trouble are you running into in your attempt to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener for the keydown event to your document. Each event has an assessible code and key property -- where the code represents the physical location on the keyboard and key is representation of the character. You can therefore scroll on all keydown events, or use `e.code` or `e.key` to scroll conditionally on only certain keydown events.

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleScrollOnKeydown);

    function handleScrollOnKeydown(e) {
      console.log('code, key', e.code, e.key);
      // Scroll on all keydown events or conditionally scroll based on code or key
    }
```